# How do I check if a mocked class method was calledin minitest?

Tags: unit-testing, mocking, ruby-on-rails-5, minitest, ruby-on-rails-5.1

I'm using Minitest and Ruby on Rails 5.  How do I assert that a void class method was called?  I have this in my class

```
module WebsocketClient
  class Proxy
    ...
    def self.authenticate(ws)
      auth_str = 'auth_str'
      ws.send auth_str
    end
```

Then in my minitest file I have

```
  # Call the connect method
  WebsocketClient::Proxy.stub(:authenticate) do
    ws_client = WebsocketClient::Proxy.new(stratum_worker)
    ws_client.connect

    msg = WebSocket::Frame::Incoming::Client.new
    msg.data = error_str
    ws_client.websocket.emit :message, msg

    # Somehow verify that authenticate was called.
  end
```

but I'm uncertain how to check if my "authenticate" method was indeed invoked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the `Spy` gem

https://github.com/ryanong/spy

And then you will do it like below

```
 # Call the connect method
  WebsocketClient::Proxy.stub(:authenticate) do
    ws_client = WebsocketClient::Proxy.new(stratum_worker)
    authenticate_spy = Spy.on(ws_client, :authenticate).and_call_through
    ws_client.connect

    msg = WebSocket::Frame::Incoming::Client.new
    msg.data = error_str
    ws_client.websocket.emit :message, msg

    # Somehow verify that authenticate was called.
    assert authenticate_spy.has_been_called?
  end
```

If you don't want actual method to be execute and just spy on it then you will use

```
authenticate_spy = Spy.on(ws_client, :authenticate)
```

See more examples on below to get familiar with `Spy` and its concepts

https://github.com/ryanong/spy